# How to make other directives work inside uib-tab elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

**Is there a callback function for uib-tab directives I can use to refresh the inner directives after a tab has been rendered?**

I am trying to find the source of an issue with a third-party directive that appears when I use that directive inside the uib-tab directive provided by angular-bootstrap. The third-party directive is [angular-multi-slider](https://github.com/enkodellc/angular-multi-slider/) and the issue was first reported in [that repository](https://github.com/enkodellc/angular-multi-slider/issues/1#issuecomment-155534915).

A use case is available [in plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dQaJAJzOcKOKA18m25hW?p=preview). Click on the second tab, and you will see that the inner slider has all its handles one on top of the others (i.e., widths=0px). Then click on one of the handles and it will appear correctly. The issue persists even after following your recommendation regarding scopes in the [FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#my-input--select-element-doesnt-work-as-expected-inside-the-tab--accordion-directive).

**Angular App**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('multiSliderDemo', ['angularMultiSlider', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('multiSliderDemo')
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $sce, $uibModal) {
    var s = [
                {value: 2, title:"Brainstorming", component: "Proposal Making", 
                   symbol: $sce.trustAsHtml("1")},
                {value: 50, title:"Working groups formation", component: "Proposal Making", 
                   symbol: $sce.trustAsHtml("2")},
                {value: 100, title:"Proposal drafting",component:"Proposal Making", 
                   symbol: $sce.trustAsHtml("3")},
                {value: 130, title:"Proposal editing", component: "Versioning", 
                   symbol: $sce.trustAsHtml("4")},
                {value: 160, title:"Proposal selection", component: "Versioning", 
                   symbol: $sce.trustAsHtml("5")},
                {value: 200, title:"Discussion of proposals", component: "Deliberation", 
                   symbol: $sce.trustAsHtml("6")},
                {value: 250, title:"Technical assessment", component: "Deliberation", 
                   symbol: $sce.trustAsHtml("7")},
                {value: 300, title:"Voting on proposals", component: "Voting", 
                   symbol: $sce.trustAsHtml("8")}
    ];

        $scope.app = {sliders:s}


  });
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="multiSliderDemo">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Multi Slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="multislider.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" class="container">
  <article>
    <h2>Multi-Slider Issue with uib-tabs</h2>
    <form name="sliderForm" id="sliderForm" novalidate autocomplete="off">
      <fieldset class="row">
        <uib-tabset>
          <uib-tab heading="Tab 1" active="true">
            <multi-slider name="mySlider"
                        floor="0"
                        step="1"
                        precision="2"
                        ceiling="365"
                        bubbles="true"
                        ng-model="app.sliders">
              </multi-slider>
          </uib-tab>
          <uib-tab heading="Tab 2" active="false">
            <section class="col-sm-6 padding-10">
              <multi-slider name="mySlider"
                        floor="0"
                        step="1"
                        precision="2"
                        ceiling="365"
                        bubbles="true"
                        ng-model="app.sliders">
              </multi-slider>
            </section>
          </uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </article>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="multislider.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.angular-multi-slider {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
height: 5px;
width: 100%;
margin: 25px 5px 25px 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.angular-multi-slider div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
}
.angular-multi-slider div.bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.angular-multi-slider div.handle {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    background-color: #13b6ff; /*can override with color in slider object*/
    border: 2px solid #000;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    -ms-transition: .3s;
    -moz-transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
    transition-property: background-color;
}
.angular-multi-slider div.handle:hover,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle:focus,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle:active,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle.active {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
    filter: brightness(70%);
}
.angular-multi-slider div.handle:hover + .bubble,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle:focus + .bubble,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle.grab + .bubble,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle:hover,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle:focus,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle.grab {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 9999;
}
.angular-multi-slider div.handle.grab + .bubble,
.angular-multi-slider div.handle.grab{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.angular-multi-slider div.bubble {
    display: none;
    cursor: default;
    top: -36px;
    padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -o-transition: .1s;
    -ms-transition: .1s;
    -moz-transition: .1s;
    -webkit-transition: .1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: top;
    transition-property: top;
}
.angular-multi-slider div.bubble:nth-child(2) {
    top: 34px !important;
    z-index:9999;
}
.angular-multi-slider div.bubble.active {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
}
.angular-multi-slider div.limit {
    margin-top: 12px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Multislider.js**

```
 'use strict';

angular.module('angularMultiSlider', [])
.directive('multiSlider', function($compile, $timeout) {
  var events = {
    mouse: {
      start: 'mousedown',
      move: 'mousemove',
      end: 'mouseup'
    },
    touch: {
      start: 'touchstart',
      move: 'touchmove',
      end: 'touchend'
    }
  };

  function roundStep(value, precision, step, floor) {
    var remainder = (value - floor) % step;
    var steppedValue = remainder > (step / 2) ? 
                       value + step - remainder : value - remainder;
    var decimals = Math.pow(10, precision);
    var roundedValue = steppedValue * decimals / decimals;
    return parseFloat(roundedValue.toFixed(precision));
  }

  function offset(element, position) {
    return element.css({
      left: position
    });
  }

  function pixelize(position) {
    return parseInt(position) + "px";
  }

  function contain(value) {
    if (isNaN(value)) return value;
    return Math.min(Math.max(0, value), 100);
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      floor       : '@',
      ceiling     : '@',
      step        : '@',
      precision   : '@',
      bubbles     : '@',
      sliders     : '=ngModel'
    },
    template :
      '<div class="bar"></div>' +
      '<div class="limit floor">{{ floor }}</div>' +
      '<div class="limit ceiling">{{ ceiling }}</div>',

    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      //base copy to see if sliders returned to original
      var original;

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        original = angular.copy(scope.sliders);
      };

      element.addClass('angular-multi-slider');

      // DOM Components
      var sliderStr = '';
      angular.forEach(scope.sliders, function(slider, key){
          sliderStr += ('<div class="handle">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bubble">{{ sliders[' + key.toString() 
                               + '].title }}{{ sliders[' + key.toString() 
                               + '].value}}
                        </div>');
      });
      var sliderControls = angular.element(sliderStr);
      element.append(sliderControls);
      $compile(sliderControls)(scope);


      var children  = element.children();
      var bar       = angular.element(children[0]),
        ngDocument  = angular.element(document),
        floorBubble = angular.element(children[1]),
        ceilBubble  = angular.element(children[2]),
        bubbles = [],
        handles = [];

      //var sliderChildren = sliderControls.children();
      angular.forEach(scope.sliders, function(slider, key) {
        handles.push(angular.element(children[(key * 2) + 3]));
        bubbles.push(angular.element(children[(key * 2) + 4]));
      });

      // Control Dimensions Used for Calculations
      var handleHalfWidth = 0,
        barWidth = 0,
        minOffset = 0,
        maxOffset = 0,
        minValue = 0,
        maxValue = 0,
        valueRange = 0,
        offsetRange = 0;

      if (scope.step === undefined) scope.step = 1;
      if (scope.floor === undefined) scope.floor = 0;
      if (scope.ceiling === undefined) scope.ceiling = 500;
      if (scope.precision === undefined) scope.precision = 0;
      if (scope.bubbles === undefined) scope.bubbles = false;

      var bindingsSet = false;

      var updateCalculations = function() {
        scope.floor = roundStep(parseFloat(scope.floor), parseInt(scope.precision), 
                      parseFloat(scope.step), parseFloat(scope.floor));
        scope.ceiling = roundStep(parseFloat(scope.ceiling), parseInt(scope.precision), 
                      parseFloat(scope.step), parseFloat(scope.floor));

        angular.forEach(scope.sliders, function(slider) {
          slider.value = roundStep(parseFloat(slider.value), parseInt(scope.precision), 
                      parseFloat(scope.step), parseFloat(scope.floor));
        });

        handleHalfWidth = handles[0][0].offsetWidth / 2;
        barWidth = bar[0].offsetWidth;
        minOffset = 0;
        maxOffset = barWidth - handles[0][0].offsetWidth;
        minValue = parseFloat(scope.floor);
        maxValue = parseFloat(scope.ceiling);
        valueRange = maxValue - minValue;
        offsetRange = maxOffset - minOffset;
      };

      var updateDOM = function () {

        updateCalculations();

        var percentOffset = function (offset) {
          return contain(((offset - minOffset) / offsetRange) * 100);
        };

        var percentValue = function (value) {
          return contain(((value - minValue) / valueRange) * 100);
        };

        var pixelsToOffset = function (percent) {
          return pixelize(percent * offsetRange / 100);
        };

        var setHandles = function () {
          offset(ceilBubble, pixelize(barWidth - ceilBubble[0].offsetWidth));
          angular.forEach(scope.sliders, function(slider,key){
            if (slider.color) {
              handles[key].css({ "background-color": slider.color });
            }

            offset( handles[key], 
                    pixelsToOffset(percentValue(slider.value)));
            offset( bubbles[key], 
                    pixelize(handles[key][0].offsetLeft 
                    - (bubbles[key][0].offsetWidth / 2) + handleHalfWidth));
          });
        };

        var bind = function (handle, bubble, currentRef, events) {
          var onEnd = function () {
            handle.removeClass('grab');
            bubble.removeClass('grab');
            if (!(''+scope.bubbles === 'true')) {
              bubble.removeClass('active');
            }

            ngDocument.unbind(events.move);
            ngDocument.unbind(events.end);

            if (angular.equals(scope.sliders, original)) {
              ngModel.$setPristine();
            }

            scope.$apply();
          };

          var onMove = function (event) {
            // Suss out which event type we are capturing and get the x value
            var eventX = 0;
            if (event.clientX !== undefined) {
              eventX = event.clientX;
            }
            else if ( event.touches !== undefined && event.touches.length) {
              eventX = event.touches[0].clientX;
            }
            else if ( event.originalEvent !== undefined &&
              event.originalEvent.changedTouches !== undefined &&
              event.originalEvent.changedTouches.length) {
              eventX = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX;
            }

            var newOffset = 
                Math.max( Math.min( 
                           (eventX - element[0].getBoundingClientRect().left             
                            - handleHalfWidth), maxOffset), minOffset),
                            newPercent = percentOffset(newOffset),
                            newValue = minValue 
                                        + (valueRange * newPercent / 100.0);

            newValue = roundStep(newValue, parseInt(scope.precision), parseFloat(scope.step), 
                       parseFloat(scope.floor));
            scope.sliders[currentRef].value = newValue;

            setHandles();
            ngModel.$setDirty();
            scope.$apply();
          };

          var onStart = function (event) {
            updateCalculations();
            bubble.addClass('active grab');
            handle.addClass('active grab');
            setHandles();
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            ngDocument.bind(events.move, onMove);
            return ngDocument.bind(events.end, onEnd);
          };

          handle.bind(events.start, onStart);
        };

        var setBindings = function () {
          var method, i;
          var inputTypes = ['touch', 'mouse'];
          for (i = 0; i < inputTypes.length; i++) {
            method = inputTypes[i];
            angular.forEach(scope.sliders, function(slider, key){
              bind(handles[key], bubbles[key], key, events[method]);
            });
          }

          bindingsSet = true;
        };

        if (!bindingsSet) {
          setBindings();

          // Timeout needed because bubbles offsetWidth is incorrect
          // during initial rendering of html elements
          setTimeout( function() {
            if (''+scope.bubbles === 'true') {
              angular.forEach(bubbles, function(bubble) {
                bubble.addClass('active');
              });
            }
            //added this for tab 1...
            updateCalculations();
            setHandles();
          }, 1);
        }
      };

      // Watch Models based on mode
      scope.$watch('sliders', updateDOM);
      // Update on Window resize
      window.addEventListener('resize', updateDOM);
    }
  }
});
```

**Notes:** 
The version of AngularJS I am using is 1.4.7. The version of angular-bootstrap is 0.14.3. The version of [angular-multi-slider](https://github.com/enkodellc/angular-multi-slider/) is 0.1.1

Comment: FYI I tested the angular-range-slider which I based my control from and it DOES work in the uib-Tab. So then I hardcoded 8 handles and bubbles and removed the $compile to see if it was the dynamic DOM additions and so far no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the slider on the 2nd tab is being rendered and hitting the multislider.js - updateCaclulations (or whatever function is calculating the space between the slider handles) function before the tab content area is visible.  So there is no parent space to calc from.  This [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8BQTtrcB5BE1NgSyLZlh) demonstrates using an ng-if to only render the multi-slider when the tab is active.  And since SO won't let you post an answer with a plunk without code, here it is:

```
    <uib-tabset>
      <uib-tab heading="Tab 1" active="activeTabs[0]">
        <multi-slider name="mySlider"
                    floor="0"
                    step="1"
                    precision="2"
                    ceiling="365"
                    bubbles="true"
                    ng-model="app.sliders"
                    ng-if="activeTabs[0]">
          </multi-slider>
      </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab heading="Tab 2" active="activeTabs[1]">
        <section class="col-sm-6 padding-10">
          <multi-slider name="mySlider"
                    floor="0"
                    step="1"
                    precision="2"
                    ceiling="365"
                    bubbles="true"
                    ng-model="app.sliders"
                    ng-if="activeTabs[1]">
          </multi-slider>
        </section>
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
```

controller:

```
$scope.activeTabs = [true, false];
```

Comment: This works! As the [updated plnkr examples show](http://plnkr.co/edit/dQaJAJzOcKOKA18m25hW?p=preview), using ng-if (to control when the slider is rendered) in combination with ng-click (to change the model that is used to control which tab is active) solves the issue.

Comment: Quick note: after switching back and forth a couple of times, sometimes the problem returns (just try it clicking back and fort between tabs in the example).

Comment: @cdparra, does the problem return ONLY by switching back and forth in the tabs or are you also toggling the `ng-if` value?

Comment: @icfantv I am toggling the ng-if value via ng-click function that simply changes the active tab according to which one is clicked.

Comment: I would have thought that once rendered, you'd be fine.  You probably don't want the `ng-if` to toggle back to false once true.  Try decoupling the tab's active state from the `ng-if` directive but as Rob pointed out, you do want to wait for that initial active state to happen...maybe use a one-time binding.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at this for over an hour and have tried a bunch of different things and none of them have worked.  It would be easy to blame the third party library but I suspect it's also due to how the tabs are rendered (i.e., via `replace: true`).  Yours would not be the first problem we've experienced with users having issues with tab contents.  We need to come up with a best practices for tab contents - especially when users put complex directives in the contents.

Comment: What have you tried? I created angular-multi-slider and have attempted a few items but lo luck so far either.

Comment: Rob J, below, provided a way of fixing this particular case. However, I agree with you that some best practices are needed (perhaps using ng-if/ng-click as suggested in the other answer)

Comment: I tried a TON of things and like @RobJacobs, I tried using `ng-if` but i didn't try it on the directive itself, rather a wrapper `<div>` and using a `$timeout` to flip it.  I used a long enough delay to let me switch to the second tab but it still didn't render.